# Node's Query String: order of parsed array for same query parameters

Tags: node.js, query-string

The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) of Node's Query String states:

> For example, the query string 'foo=bar&abc=xyz&abc=123' is parsed into:
>
> ```
> {
>  foo: 'bar',
>  abc: ['xyz', '123']
> }
> ```

Still it doesn't explicitly state that the order of values for same parameters in the URL is always preserved. Is this guaranteed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Values are appended to the end of an array:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/querystring.js#L250

Comment: mmh ok according to the source, the order gets preserved. It would be nice if they would state it explicitly in the docs.